# прочитанное из stdin дублируется в stdout

Tags: r, ввод

при чтении данных из [стандартного потока](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) ввода (*stdin*) они дублируются и в стандартный поток вывода (*stdout*). примеры:

```
$ echo "10" | r -e 'x<-readLines()'
10
$ echo "10" | r -e 'x<-scan(quiet=T)'
1: 10
2:
```

как избежать этого дублирования?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

хотя в описании обеих функций и написано, что по умолчанию чтение происходит из *stdin*, следует явно открыть *stdin* с помощью функции `file()`, и передать созданный ею объект упомянутым функциям чтения (аргумент `con` для `readLines()` и `file` для `scan()`).

```
$ echo "10" | r -e 'x<-readLines(con=file("stdin"))'
$ echo "10" | r -e 'x<-scan(file=file("stdin"),quiet=T)'
$
```

---

примеры, дополненные реальной обработкой введённых данных и выводом результатов:

```
$ echo "10" | r -e 'x<-readLines(con=file("stdin")); cat(as.numeric(x[1])+1)'
11
$ echo "10" | r -e 'x<-scan(file=file("stdin"),quiet=T); cat(x[1]+1)'
11
```

---

p.s. в случае функции `scan()` можно даже обойтись без вызова функции `file()`, сразу передав аргументу `file` значение `stdin`:

```
$ echo "10" | r -e 'x<-scan(file="stdin",quiet=T); cat(x[1]+1)'
11
```